# Locally hosted Google Font not loading

Tags: css, font-face

I would like to host Google fonts locally on a webhosting server.
However, the fonts are not loading. I tried to simplify the implementation and used these styles in my `index.html`:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff') format('woff'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype'),
    }

    body{ font-family:"Open Sans",serif; }
</style>
```

The `.woff` and `.ttf` files located in the root beside of the `index.html`.

I have provided the fallback font `'serif'` to try and pin down the error.
The site always shows the fallback `'serif'` instead of `'Open Sans'`.
In the DevTools 'Sources' Tab I can see that the font was not loading, but there is no error in the 'Console' or the Server-Log.

How can I fix this?

**Update**: like CrissCrossCrass's hint, there was an syntax error. After the last src-definition there has to be a semicolon instead of a comma (after format:('truetype')). Correct styling was:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
        }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.woff') format('woff'),
            url('open-sans-v15-latin-700.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

    body{ font-family:"Open Sans",serif; }
</style>
```

Comment: 2 things i noticed, first "why using the same font-face command twice?" and second "format('truetype'),
    }" i am pretty sure there should be an semicolon(;) instead of a comma :)

Comment: Yes, you are the best. That was exactly the problem! The last font format (truetype) have to has a semicolon instead of comma.

Answer (score 0):

How is your file directory structured? There is a possibility that the references to your font files do not actually point to your font files. Also, you would want the style tag to be placed before your HTML tags.

Comment: The reference was correct, the error was in syntax (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Open `Network` tab in developer tools and see if the files are actually loaded if not and you get `NOT FOUND` then check your directory structure.

Comment: There was no 'not found', because there was an error in syntax (see below).

Comment: @IFY yeah, I saw that now. Now problem's solved so continue with the good work. Best of luck.